# python unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'function

Tags: python

I am having trouble with my python with the fact it keep return me with this error code

```
 total_amount = loanpayment * years * 12
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'int'
```

```
def loanpayment(principal, percentage, years):
    i = (percentage/100)/12
    n = years * 12
    P = principal
    loanpayment = (i*principal*((1+i)**n))/(((1+i)**n)-1)
    return loanpayment

principal = int(input(""))
percentage = float(input(""))
years = int(input(""))
num_payments = years * 12

total_amount = loanpayment * years * 12

print("Monthly payment : {}".format(loanpayment(principal,percentage,years)))
print("Total interest paid", interest, ".")
```

Comment: Having a variable and a function which share the same name is a bad idea, and it has clearly led to some confusion.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for me? What should I do to get better on naming?

Comment: Well in the code above `loanpayment` is the problematic name. Do you mean general naming-related suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`loanpayment` is a function.

you need to call it with parameters.

in your case:

```
loanpayment(principal, percentage, years)
```

the full line:

```
total_amount =  loanpayment(principal, percentage, years) * years * 12
```

Comment: Also isn't there a naming problem? line 5: `loanpayment` is also a variable withing the body of the function. Couldn't that cause a conflict?

Comment: @Clepsyd No, because that variable declaration remains in the local scope of the function. You'd have to force it to become global, in which case it would indeed break things.